# How to remove lag from RTSP stream playing in a VideoView on Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp, vlc, lag

My goal is to have a computer stream the video from a usb webcam to my own android app.

On the PC I'm running VLC which streams the capture device (webcam) over RTSP on port 8554, with the following settings:

```
Video Codec: H.264
Video Resolution: 1600x1200 x 0.25= 400 x 300 px
Video Frame Rate: 12 fps
Video Bitrate: 56 Kbps
and NO audio
```

I picked very low settings to see if it would improve lag but had little to no effect on lag. This is the generated output stream string VLC gives me:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=56,fps=12,scale=0.25,acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :sout-keep
```

On android side in the onCreate Method I have:

```
String url = "rtsp://192.168.1.103:8554/";
vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
mc = new MediaController(this);
vid.setMediaController(mc);
vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
vid.requestFocus();
vid.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vid.start();
    }
});
```

Results:

When the app loads up VideoView is all black for about 10-20 seconds while two messages pop up in LogCat:

```
Tag             Text
MediaPlayer     Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
MediaPlayer     getMetadata
```

once the video is displayed, there's about 20 seconds of lag and after about 30-60 seconds the video remains frozen. These messages also come up once the video starts playing:

```
Tag             Text
MediaPlayer     info/warning (3, 0)
MediaPlayer     Info (3, 0)
```

I also tried capturing the stream from another PC on the same network with VLC, it seems that the lag is still there as well however it never freezes. Not sure whether I should use a different RTSP server, such as Darwin? use a different protocol, HTTP or RTP? or if something needs to be changed on the android side?

Comment: did you solve the problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try http stream from VLC. You can never remove all the lag when transcoding, but should be able to get it down to < 10 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure you can get a lagless solution with a `VideoView`. Android's RTSP support seems pretty weak: when I tried to playback a VLC-generated video stream, I kept getting an "Unsupported format" error, even though VLC (and other players) could handle the stream just fine.

When we tried http streaming, we got a whopping 90 seconds of lag!

In the end, I wrote my own minimal RTSP client, and passed the H264 packets directly to a [`MediaCodec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html). This took a 'decent' amount of code (3200+ lines) and was 'reasonably' difficult, but the latency was well under a second. (This was with a camera that does H264 encoding in hardware; a software encoder will probably impose a higher minimum lag.)

Comment: Do you plan to open source the code for this client?